# Input Different Length Stings in c++?

Tags: c++

I want to take different length strings without knowing their length and distributing their characters in arrays as input in c++.

1. Take number of strings (3)
2. Take first string. Example: `hello` and it should be saved like

   ```
   a[]={'h','e','l','l','o'}
   ```
3. Take second string
4. Take third string

Comment: Could you please post your entire code for this problem and be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish in step 4?

Comment: 3 //number of strings
---+-++- //first string
+++++ 4 //second string
-+-+- 4 //third string

Comment: Is there some reason not to use std::string?

Comment: @KennyOstrom i am a beginner please help  me by giving snippet code.

Comment: The correct way would be to use the std::string, and NOT put them in a char array.  Just add them to a std::vector<std::string>

Answer (score -1):

To store the characters of a string in an array, you could try this:

```
string string1 = "Hello";
char a[string1.length()+1];
for (int i = 0; i < string1.length(); i++)
{
   a[i] = string1[i];
}
```

That will loop through the entire string and by using .length(), store the indexed values in a[]. If you have several strings, just repeat the process.

Comment: string s[10];
    
    
        for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
        {
            cin>>s[i];
         
        }
        for(int j=0;j<t;j++)
        {
            cout<<s[j]<<end;
        }

Comment: Now i want to convert the string which is stored in s[1] into a new array of characters.Sorry for not being soo clear

Comment: like std::string::data() or std::string::c_str() ?

Comment: what's the length of a in this answer?

Comment: @kennyOstrom length of a depends on length of string.

Comment: Better, but that's a non-standard extension. Also you rewrote a standard function strcpy.